# Word "save as" folder no longer original folder after Mavericks

Tags: macos, ms-office, folders

Following upgrade to Mavericks, Word for Mac 2011 has different "save as" behavior.

WAS: "save as" would default to the directory of the current/open file.

Now: "save as" directory goes to word default, requiring navigating back to original drive/folder/subfolders.

Problem further described in this support thread: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23824310#23824310

I'm a lawyer and saving new versions of a document with new dates or marked changes is industry standard (no internal "versions" for us!) as a method of version control. I believe more people must have this problem. Time-wasting and incredibly hard to change a process that's been in place for years and years.

Comment: Could you comment or edit if you still have questions after reviewing the linked question... Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to connect the dots. However, the linked question is not the same issue at all. 
The linked question is about saving a version, which is distinct and separate from save or save as, and is further asking about selecting a particular version when reverting from the current to a saved version.